# Access html5 data-* attributes defined in a module script

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

When loading scripts without using modules, I could use the `document.currentscript` to access custom attributes.

E.g.

```
<script src="js/myscript.js" data-custom-attribute="my-value"></script>
```

Within myscript.js I can then do the following

```
// will contain "my-value"
const myAttribute = document.currentScript.getAttribute('data-custom-attribute');
```

If I load the javascript using module syntax however, the `currentScript` is set to null and this doesn't work.

```
<script src="js/myscript.js" data-custom-attribute="my-value" type="module"></script>
```

Is there a way to still access such attributes within the javascript file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)

> The Document.currentScript property returns the  element whose
> script is currently being processed ***and isn't a JavaScript module***.
> (For modules use import.meta instead.)

`import.meta` does not provide the data-attribute. Here are a few alternatives:

[**edit may 2022**] The import from the original snippet does not exist anymore. Though it's still loaded from `cdn.jsdelivr.net`, this may in the future not be the case. So, added a new snippet using a more [persistent library](https://github.com/KooiInc/JQL).

```html
<script data-custom-attribute="my-value" type="module">
  import {Logger} from 
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KooiInc/DOM-Utilities@v1.1.2/SmallHelpers.js";
  const log = Logger();
  log(`document.currentScript is ${document.currentScript}`);
  log(`But with querySelector ... data-custom-attribute from module script: ${
    document.querySelector("script[type=module]").dataset.customAttribute}`);
  log(`Or more precize: document.querySelector("script[data-custom-attribute]"): ${
    document.querySelector("script[data-custom-attribute]")
      .dataset.customAttribute}`);
  log(`Or retrieve and filter document.scripts: ${[...document.scripts]
      .find(scrpt => scrpt.dataset.customAttribute).dataset.customAttribute}`);
</script>
```

```html
<script type="module" data-custom-attribute="my-value">
  import $ from "https://kooiinc.github.io/JQL/lib/JQLBundle.js";
  $.setStyle(`#result`, {whiteSpace: `nowrap`});
  $.setStyle(`#result div`, {marginTop: `0.3rem`});
  $.setStyle(`code`, {color: `green`});
  const log = (...lines) => 
    lines.forEach( line => $(`#result`).html(`<div>${line}</div>`, true));
  const indent = `<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;`;
  
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  log(`<code>document.currentScript</code> = ${document.currentScript}`); 
  log(`But<br>
    <code>document.querySelector("script[type=module]")
    .dataset.customAttribute</code> = "${ 
     document.querySelector("script[type=module]").dataset.customAttribute}"`);
  log(`Or targeted exactly<br> 
    <code>document.querySelector("script[data-custom-attribute]")
    ${indent}.dataset.customAttribute</code> = "${ 
    document.querySelector("script[data-custom-attribute]")
      .dataset.customAttribute}"`); 
  log(`Or retrieve from <code>document.scripts</code><br>
    <code>[...document.scripts].find(scrpt =>
       ${indent}scrpt.dataset.customAttribute).dataset.customAttribute</code> = "${
        [...document.scripts].find(scrpt => scrpt.dataset.customAttribute)
          .dataset.customAttribute}"`);
</script>

<div id="result"></result>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more robust way of knowing the attributes with which my script is called, but if the custom attribute is unique this is indeed a nice alternative, thanks

Comment: There is no 'robust' way for module scripts. I've added another alternative to the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution to this problem, but I wanted to point out that there can also be a problem with *non* module scripts not showing `document.currentScript.getAttribute(...)`. The problem may be specific to Firefox. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209092/why-document-currentscript-has-no-attributes-when-the-script-element-is-added-dy).