# Why document.currentScript has no attributes when the script element is added dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, dom

I have a script as follows.

```
<script myattribute="myvalue">
  console.log(document.currentScript.attributes);
</script>
```

When the script is part of index.html, a NamedNodeMap object with a length property of value 1 (number of attributes) is logged to the console. If the script is added dynamically through another script, a NamedNodeMap object with a length property of value 0 is logged to the console.

Why is it that the NamedNodeMap object has the length property of value 0 when the script is loaded dynamically?

Supposing that no changes can be made within the script, is there any workaround for the script to consume the attributes specified in the script tag?

Comment: Can you show us the code that loads your script dynamically? Are you sure that it is adding the `myattribute` to the script tag?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to resolve with that custom attribute? Maybe we could resolve that ..?

Comment: @Terry The code for loading the script dynamically is as follows:
`const scriptElement = document.createElement('script'); scriptElement.setAttribute('myattribute', 'myvalue'); scriptElement.innerHTML = "console.log(document.currentScript.attributes);" document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);`
And yes, the attribute is added to the script tag.

Comment: @Teemu I need to a third party js file which needs api keys to be passed as attributes on the script tag. And the js file accessess the api keys using `document.currentScript` which in turn doesn't have the attributes when the script is loaded dynamically

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ep5q31u7/2/), your issue is not reproducible.

Comment: @Teemu This reproduces for me on Firefox 94 for Mac. The problem persists even for standard attributes, like `id`. The actual problem I'm trying to resolve is a way to pass parameters from the HTML into a Javascript file.

Comment: I can also reproduce on Chrome for Mac.